# C++ No console output when initializing string variables in code

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, atom-editor

I'm new to C++ and I recently installed the **Atom IDE** and the **MinGW gcc and g++ Files**.

However, whenever I try to initialize a string variable in my code, no console output is shown.

[Without string variable:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nysi.png)

[With string variable:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKJ41.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string month, day, year;

    cout << "Enter date: ";

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I fixed the issue by moving the path to MinGW/bin first in the PATH, I'm assuming some other library is messing with the MinGW library but I dont know where

Comment: What happens when you try to debug it? Code looks fine

Comment: Please post your code here (not links) links can die and it's no help to future readers.

Comment: You don't initialize your string to anything. And you don't send the string to
`std::getline(std::cin, variable);` When you ask to enter date, nothing is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried out your code on Code::Blocks 13.12 and it worked fine. I would suggest trying a different IDE.

Comment: Yes I tested it on Code::Blocks too and It's fine, but I really like this IDE and I've seen it work for others.